# How to configure the endpoints for the "new" windows azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've just created a "new" virtual machine in Windows Azure. I say "new" because there is a "Virtual Machine (classic)" option.

The "new" virtual machine is not accesible by the "old" https://manage.windowsazure.com, it's only accesible by the "new" https://portal.azure.com

My problem is that I've expent a couple of days configuring the "new" Virtual Machine and now I want to open the port 80... but I don't find the "endpoint" configuration!!

I've been looking for it many hours :S

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Resource Managed VMs now use the concept of Network adapters, Virtual Networks and Security Groups to manage ingress, egress from a machine.

A virtual machine has a network adapter attached, the adapter is placed within a subnet within a virtual network. A security group can then be placed against the subnet and / or the network adapter.

The network adapter can optionally have a publically accessible address bound to it. Either dynamically or statically bound (i.e. if you take a fixed address, you will be charged for it for when the machine isn't running)

I'm not entirely sure its possible to create a security group via the portal (at least I couldn't find any option for it when I just (albeit briefly) looked.

However you can use [New-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125827.aspx) to create a security group and then attach it to your Nic through the portal and also configure the security policy. Which you get to via -

Virtual machines -> VNMame-> Settings -> Network interfaces -> NicName -> Choose network security group

It is a little more complicated than the previous method, but once you're used to it it is a lot more flexible.

*Edited to add*

Depending on your config, you might need to a public IP address attaching also - use [New-AzurePublicIpAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt126026.aspx)

Comment: I've just found a way of doing this with the portal. Just search for "Security Group" and configure the inbound and onbound rules.

Comment: I've been trying for days to make this work. I created a VM, added a webserver to the VM and opened port 80 as an inbound rule in the NSG. Whenever I try to access the VM through port 80 using the public IP, I get a connection timeout. I have no problem connecting using SSH (or RDP for windows) using the same public IP. I havn't configured anything but the inbound port rules and installing the webserver on the VM. The firewall is disabled inside the VM and the webserver responds to "localhost". What am I missing?

Comment: @Impero that's an interesting one! Post that as a question and maybe include the resource definition (from resource explorer) and I'm sure we'll be able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

It's all good. The get-help wasn't up to date and optional params are actually needed. Just make sure to use all params